# How to re-generate a previously saved SIRC protocol waveform?

Tags: arduino, infrared

I am trying to replicate the remote control for my Sony home theater system. I started with anaylzing the demodulated signal of power on button using a [TSOP1738](http://datasheet.octopart.com/TSOP1738-Vishay-datasheet-49890.pdf) IR demodulator. It looks like this:

[image]

You can see the signal (along with the decoded command).
Next I replicated the signal using the Arduino (and as per [SIRC protocol](http://www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/sirc.php), chose 1/4 duty @ 38Khz). Below is the signal of a complete one to show the code sent and a zoomed one to show the 38Khz 25% duty burst within the signal.

[image]

[image]

Now to drive an IR LED using this signal, I fed this into a [2N2222](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/PN/PN2222A.pdf) NPN BJT transistor's base with its collector connected to +5V and base to IR LED -> Series Resistance -> GND. And to test the signal I fed this "generated" signal through the TSOP1738 again and probed the output.

[image: schematic diagram]

The signal I get looks like an IR signal except for the 1's (when TSOP1738 goes LOW) instead of being LOW for a duration, as in the first image. I see a lot of toggling going on:

[image]

The "generated" signal, of course, does not work. Any idea what's going in here ?

Comment: You might want to edit the line in your question which currently states "... and **base** to IR LED -> Series Resistance -> GND.". Also, a schematic solves many doubts, please add one to your question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Here it is http://i.imgur.com/7PrhAl.png

Comment: For one thing, with a 100K base resistor, you're really limiting the drive to the LED. Depending on the exact gain of the transistor, the LED is probably getting only about 5 mA, not the 50 mA you might expect. This may also be creating issues with the switching speed of the transistor. You should put a scope (not a logic analyzer) on the collector and see if you're getting a clean waveform there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I do not have "Comment" privileges, I'm responding in Answer form, though this is not an answer:

- Are you sure your IR LED is connected to the base of the transistor as you state, and not like the first schematic on [this page](http://www.ladyada.net/make/tvbgone/design.html)?
- Is the IR LED you are using, of the same IR wavelength as is expected by the [TSOP1738](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/208/301092_DS.pdf), i.e. 950 nanometer or therabouts?

**Possible answer:**
Your oscilloscope trace of the Arduino generated signal shows a PWM frequency of 39.215 KHz, and the final signal trace shows effects typical of aliasing between two windows of slightly different frequencies. Try getting your output closer to the nominal 38KHz, and recapture results for this discussion, please.

[**Edit**: *Woohoo, I just received "Comment anywhere" privileges! So I'll leave this answer in place and amend it towards a valid answer if I can.*]

Comment: That's exactly how i have my led wired up. the base of the transistor is connected to the Arduino output pin through a resistor

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the "aliasing" bit. Where would the other similar frequency come from? Granted my generated signal is not exactly 38Khz but my understanding is that deviating from the demodulator frequency a little bit might affect the sensitivity/effectiveness of my IR signal but it should still have the same trace overall ...

Comment: From the 38KHz notch filter of the TSOP part.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Followed your suggestion and the code to get closer to 38Khz. The toggling is much less as seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/49Ga1.png). **Noticed another thing which i missed before the 0's in waveform are with time period approx 2.84msec(whereas in my code its for 1.2msec). So almost twice of what I coded it for**

Comment: The previous version of code might actually gave worked better with a TSOP1740.  :-)

Comment: Still not sure what was wrong but I solved the problem by using timers to generate the 38Khz wave instead of doing in manually.

Comment: Which means you now know what was wrong: The difference between your earlier transmission carrier frequency and the 38khz filter frequency of theTSOP part was causing the incoming pulses to sometimes fall just outside the filters "open" time slot, to simplify the idea. This would fall afoul of the comparator in there, hence the spikes in what should have been a flat portion of the waveform.

Comment: If your not knowing what was wrong refers to why the bit bang signal was not precisely 38 khz: Perhaps you did not account for stack pushes and pops in your code, or the cycles needed to actually execute the computations for each pulse and the instructions to write to the port. Another factor contributing to frequency drift is the MCU clock precision, especially applicable when using internal or RC clocks, or clock rates within an order of magnitude or three of the desired output resolution.